# What is the 'SFDC_Devconsole' debug level?

Tags: apex, batch, debug-logs

I am trying to retrieve error logs for a batch apex class and am creating a new user trace flag for the running user. The standard preset is 'SFDC_Devconsole' - will this trigger debug logs to show for this user or do I need to create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SFDC_DevConsole` will include plenty of debug log for the running user, some would say too much verbosity

```
DB: INFO
Callouts: INFO
ApexCode: DEBUG
Validation: INFO
Workflow: INFO
Profiling: INFO
System: DEBUG (way too much verbosity here)
```

Note that for batchables, there will be many log entries

- 1 for the `start()`
- *n* (1 for each `execute()`)
- 1 for the `finish()`